# Match lists based on Name and DOB

Tags: python

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for...I have two lists of people, FirstName, LastName, Date of Birth, and I just want to know which people are in both lists, and which ones are in one but not the other.

I've tried something like

```
common = pd.merge(list1, list2, how='left', left_on=['Last', 'First', 'DOB'], right_on=['Patient Last Name', 'Patient First Name', 'Date of Birth']).dropna()
```

Based on something else I found online, but it give me this error:

```
KeyError: 'Date of Birth'
```

I've verified that that is indeed the column heading in the second list, so I don't get what's wrong.  Anyone do matching like this?  What's the easiest/fastest way? The names may have different formatting between lists, like "Smith-Jones" vs. "SmithJones" vs. "Smith Jones", but I get around that by stripping all spances and punctuation from the names...I assume that's a first good step?

Comment: Look into set unions and differences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it should work

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO


import pandas as pd

TESTDATA=StringIO("""DOB;First;Last
    2016-07-26;John;smith
    2016-07-27;Mathew;George
    2016-07-28;Aryan;Singh
    2016-07-29;Ella;Gayau
    """)

list1 = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")

TESTDATA=StringIO("""Date of Birth;Patient First Name;Patient Last Name
    2016-07-26;John;smith
    2016-07-27;Mathew;XXX
    2016-07-28;Aryan;Singh
    2016-07-20;Ella;Gayau
    """)


list2 = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")

print list2
print list1

common = pd.merge(list1, list2, how='left', left_on=['Last', 'First', 'DOB'], right_on=['Patient Last Name', 'Patient First Name', 'Date of Birth']).dropna()
print common
```

Comment: Also to get the ones that are missing follow the code mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284409/how-to-subtract-rows-of-one-pandas-data-frame-from-another