# for each row in df subtract another df

Tags: python, pandas

Example.

```
df1 is 1000 x 20
df2 is subset of df1 10 x 20
```

I want each row of df1 to subtract df2 and summing it together. This will return another df3 as 1000 x 10

Comment: Something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284409/how-to-subtract-rows-of-one-pandas-data-frame-from-another?

Comment: Why would you drop 10 columns?

Comment: So for each row 1 x 20 you want to subtract a df 10 x 20, how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy broadcast feature to do this. For that you need to reshape your data to make it broadcastable

you can do something similar to sudo code below

```py
df1_data = df1.values.reshape(-1, 10, 20)
df2_data = df2.values

result = df1_data - df2_data  # this will give array of shape 100*10*20

result.reshape(-1, 20) # will give array of shape 1000*20

# you can now use the result to create a data frame or use it in further calcualations
```

Comment: Hi Dev, I guess I wasn't clear. I wanted each value of df1 to subtract df2 and consolidated.