# How to (fast) iterate over two Dataframes (Pandas) with functions applied for comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 Datasets from different sources and I like to filter redundancy. So i have a function called "compare_df" that takes 1 row from each df and compares them, when they match it returns True, else False.

But "compare_df" is more complex because the information are not formatted the same, and I check for time window overlaps so simply checking if elements match is not possible.
Also there are no matching columns in both df.

My current solution is using apply twice like in this code:

```
 result_df = first_df[first_df.apply(lambda x: ~second_df.apply(
        compare_df, axis=1,
        args=[x, no_end_time, ]).any(), axis=1)]
```

Is there an easy way to optimize the code, so that it runs faster.
Maybe it is possible to just "break" the second apply function as soon as a "True" value is returned.
Using itterrows should be slower btw. because there shouldn't be as much redundancy, so the benefit of the easy breaking of the loop probably won't outperform the faster apply function from pandas.

(I know numba could help, but it seems too complicated for this simple task)

Thanks for suggestions and other hints!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to subtract rows of one pandas data frame from another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284409/how-to-subtract-rows-of-one-pandas-data-frame-from-another)

Comment: not really because as i said, i need to apply a complex function on whether the two rows "mean" the same thing or not - they are not formatted the same way and they don't need to share the explicitly same information. For that to find out i need to apply my own function "compare_df".